# What is the WebAPI alternative for AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>()?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When working with .NET identity in web APIs, you don't find AddDefaultIdentity method to add identity to DI service.AddDefaultIdentity is a method found in Web UIs and not in APIs.

What is the alternative for this in web APIs?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core Web APIs, you typically don't use the AddDefaultIdentity method because it's intended for MVC or Razor Pages applications, not for APIs. In APIs, you usually want more control over the authentication mechanisms and don't need all the features provided by AddDefaultIdentity.

For Web APIs, you can add authentication using AddAuthentication and then configure the authentication scheme you want to use. Here's a basic example of how you might set up JWT (JSON Web Token) authentication in a .NET Core Web API:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"]))
    };
});

services.AddAuthorization();
```

Then, in your Configure method, you'll want to add the authentication middleware:

```
// In Configure method of Startup.cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Ensure that you have JWT-related configurations in your appsettings.json file:

```
    {
  "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "your_issuer",
    "Audience": "your_audience",
    "SecretKey": "your_secret_key"
  }
}
```

With this setup, you can use [Authorize] attribute on your controller actions or controllers to secure them, and clients need to include a valid JWT token in the Authorization header to access those endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

**builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(// your options);**

AddIdentity(): In ASP.NET Core, the AddIdentity() method is used to configure identity services in the application's dependency injection container.This method configures the identity system with options such as user requirements, password policies, and external authentication providers

AddDefaultIdentity(): In ASP.NET Core, AddDefaultIdentity() is a shorthand method to quickly configure a basic identity system with reasonable default settings. It internally calls AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>() with predefined settings for user and role configurations.

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 8 Identity, I find having only the following piece of code hassle-free:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
```